# how to change the width between columns ? HIGHCHARTS

Tags: highcharts, column-chart

I need to reduce these distances,
I tried to give a smaller width, but it doesn't help.
but the width of the columns must stay

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/x1m0et85/2/`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can control the distance by using `groupPadding` property. If the result does not suit you, you may need to reduce the chart width.

```
   plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0.1,
      groupPadding: 0.15,
      ...
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5z4cbv0p/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.groupPadding

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.width